# How to start Service on click of Widget Button?

Tags: android, widget

I am able to start Activity class on click of widget button, but when  try same for start service it's not working, let me know how can i call start service here.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code

```
startService(new Intent(this, YOUR_SERVICE_CLASS_NAME.class));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code man

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyWidget.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, i,0);
RemoteViews updateView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.n);
updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update_button,pi);
```

Comment: it's for simple activity button, but let me know how can we do this using widget Button

Comment: @Shubh, have u find solution ? I am facing similar issue, my event for widget button lost as service is not started.

Comment: @JRC It's long back but not remember correctly but you can check [button widget click not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9243146/2624806), [Start Stop Service from Widget](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17515418/2624806), OR from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2957442/2624806).