# Android Widget won't have a click

Tags: android

Basically I've got this Widget, that's supposed to show a Toast once it is clicked.

```
public class WidgetActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {


 @Override
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
     for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {  

         int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];  
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);  
         intent.setAction("ActionOne");  
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);  
         RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
         views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.LinLayWiget, pendingIntent);  
         appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);  

     }

 }



 @Override  
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

     Log.e("YYY","YYYY");
     Toast.makeText(context, "AAA", 1500).show();

     if (intent.getAction().equals("ActionOne")) {  

         Log.e("X","X");
         Toast.makeText(context, "I'm CLICKED!", 1500).show();

        }  
     super.onReceive(context, intent);  
 } 




}
```

manifest:

```
...
        <receiver android:name="WidgetActivity" android:label="FXMaster" android:icon="@drawable/assiconwi">

            <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widgetprovider" />
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"></action>
                </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
...
```

But once the widget is clicked, nothing happens. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see it get into the OnResume function? Like on debug? If in there do you see a different action? P.S. Probably better to use "ActionOne".equals(intent.getAction()) to avoid possible null pointers :-)

Comment: Also I assume that you have 'package="Fart.Widget"' in your AndroidManifest.xml right? Typically it is better to use...new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),  R.layout.widget_layout);

Comment: Thanks for the tips Jackie! I've edited the code, see above, but it still gives no results. :(

Comment: Perhaps the "LinLayWiget" element can't be clicked? Try adding an image or a button and check result?

Answer (score 3):

I am here to save you.

1) `onUpdate` override should call (in the beginning of the method for example)

```
super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
```

2) Because of this line:

```
intent.setAction("ActionOne");
```

Your intents can be ignored, so the code wonT fall into the if in the `onReceive`. Add a unique identifier like it is done in this post [Android keeps caching my intents Extras, how to declare a pending intent that keeps fresh extras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140072/android-keeps-caching-my-intents-extras-how-to-declare-a-pending-intent-that-ke)

On a last note, I d change my class name since  it is not an Activity actually.

Cheers.