# Start/Stop Service from Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I want to start a service from inside the widget, I know that i can do it using PendingIntent like

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyService.class), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonWidgetStartService, intent);
```

but the problem is that I've already used PendingIntent on that button for some other purpose.
So, I tried starting the service using

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
```

and here I'm getting `NullPointerException`.

**Here's my code:**

```
public class WiNetWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String TOGGLE_WINET = "ToggleWiNetService";
    private static boolean serviceRunning = false;
    private static Intent serviceIntent;
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        serviceIntent = new Intent(context, WiNetService.class);

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_winet);

            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonWidgetLoading, View.INVISIBLE);
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonWidgetStartService, View.VISIBLE);

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, WiNetWidget.class);
            newIntent.setAction(TOGGLE_WINET);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, newIntent, 0);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonWidgetStartService, pendingIntent);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonWidgetStopService, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
            Log.i(TOGGLE_WINET, "updated");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(TOGGLE_WINET)) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_winet);
            if(serviceRunning) {
                context.stopService(serviceIntent);
                remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonWidgetStartService, View.VISIBLE);
                remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonWidgetStopService, View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(context, "serviceStopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                context.startService(serviceIntent);
                remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonWidgetStopService, View.VISIBLE);
                remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonWidgetStartService, View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(context, "serviceStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            serviceRunning=!serviceRunning;
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, WiNetWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

Note: If I remove the lines containing `startService` and `stopService`, everything is running smoothly.

Thanks in Advance!! :)

Comment: Does it work if you use `context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));` rather than the variable `serviceIntent`?

Comment: @Neil Townsend: Thank you sir, it worked. Thanks a lot!! Can you please explain why wasn't it working before?? Thanks Again. :)

Comment: See below for fuller answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you create a one-shot `Intent` once, but use it multiple times. Better to create a fresh `Intent` every time you want to start or stop the `Service` as follows:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(TOGGLE_WINET)) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_winet);

        // Create a fresh intent 
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, WiNetService.class);

        if(serviceRunning) {
            context.stopService(serviceIntent);
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonWidgetStartService, View.VISIBLE);
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonWidgetStopService, View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "serviceStopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonWidgetStopService, View.VISIBLE);
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.buttonWidgetStartService, View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "serviceStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        serviceRunning=!serviceRunning;
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, WiNetWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```